# Azure Storage Blob Uploaded PDF file cannot be read

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

currently I'm building a function that can get PDF attachment from emails to upload them to Azure Storage Blob with `Azure.Storage.Blobs` SDK. The PDFs got saved as an `Attachment` variable and got sent to the Azure Storage just fine (as a MemoryStream) however I cannot open or read it. The error message from Acrobat Reader said that

```
Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'file.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).
```

I have set the AccessPolicy to `PublicAccessType.Blob` as well as trying to set the HTTPBlobOptions when Upload the file to `{ContentType = 'application/pdf'}`, however none of it make the PDF readable after uploading.

My current code looks something like this:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connString);
Attachment attachment = GetEmailPDF(emails);
try
   {
    BlobContainerClient blobContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobDirectoryName);
    if (blobContainer.Exists())
    {
       blobContainer.SetAccessPolicyAsync(PublicAccessType.Blob).Wait();
       string prefix_path = <my custom prefix path setup>;
       var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(prefix_path);
       //Upload PDF file
       BlobHttpHeaders blobHttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders();
       blobHttpHeaders.ContentType = attachment.ContentType.ToString();
       blobClient.UploadAsync(attachment.ContentStream, blobHttpHeaders).Wait();
       
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw new Exception("Something happened to UploadPDFFile: ", e);
}
```

Comment: What’s the size of the uploaded blob? Is it same as the attachment size?

Comment: I also just noticed that the size is smaller than the original attachment and set the position to 0. Turns out that is exactly what the issue is

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Stream's position not set to 0 is one of major cause of such kind of problem. Please post your solution as an answer so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

With the below **c#** code, I can able to read PDF attachment file from emails.

**Code:**

```cs
string connString = "<conne_string>";
string blobDirectoryName = "<container_name>";
string emailID = "<email_ID>";

BlobServiceClient BSC = new BlobServiceClient(connString);

Attachment att = Get_email_PDF(emailID);

try
{
   BlobContainerClient BC = BSC.GetBlobContainerClient(blobDirectoryName);

    if (BC.Exists())
    {
       BC.SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.Blob);
       string path = "sample.pdf";
       string file = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
       BlobClient blob_client = BC.GetBlobClient(Path.Combine(path, file));
       att.ContentStream.Position = 0;
       blob_client.Upload(att.ContentStream, true);
       blob_client.SetHttpHeaders(new BlobHttpHeaders
       {
          ContentType = "application/pdf"
        });
     }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Error while uploading a pdf: ", e);
}

static Attachment Get_email_PDF(string email)
{
    MailMessage mailMSG = new MailMessage();
    mailMSG.From = new MailAddress("<email_ID>");
    mailMSG.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
    mailMSG.Subject = "<email_Subject>";
    mailMSG.Body = "<email_Body>";
    mailMSG.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("<pdf_file_path>"));
    return mailMSG.Attachments[0];
 }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Azure portal Output :**

***Blob successfully uploaded from email to Azure portal as below:***

[image]

I can able to read the blob through the **blob URL**:

[image]

I can able to read the **pdf blob** through the the **Blob URL** as below:

[image]